# What did Grandpa eat for dessert?. Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle

"You know I love to eat" Said Grandpa.

" I ate a lot yesterday" He continued.

> " I started with a nice French Toast
>
> For my second course I had a Hot Dog!
>
> For my third course I had some Pho.
>
> Next I had tasty Tandoori Chicken
>
> For the next course I had Sushi.
>
> To end it all I had some dessert!"
>
> " What did you have?" I asked
>
> " Guess!  It was either Ice Cream or Apple Pie"

What did Grandpa have for dessert? Why?

Comment: Grandpa is going to have a lot of health issues with the amount of food he is consuming.

Comment: He played Football for Dallas Cowboys :)

Comment: "You are old, Father William..."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm going to say

> Ice Cream
>
> If you take the appropriate letter from each of the courses, you get
> **F**rench Toast
> H**o**t Dog
> Ph**o**
> Tan**d**oori Chicken
> Sush**i**
>
> So to complete the word FOODIE (which he clearly is), you'd want an 'E' in the sixth position:
> Ice Cr**e**am

Comment: This seems too consistent to not be true

Answer (score 5):

I vote for

> Apple Pie

Reasoning:

> For each row (sentence), the result of (does it have punctuation in the end) is
>  No-Yes-Yes-No-Yes-Yes,  a "mild" pattern
>  Thus, it is Apple pie because it has " after it.

Additionally:

> Even if this is not the answer, punctuation definitely has to do something with it. IMO, there's no way OP "accidentally" included a needless period in the title.

I cannot for the love of all create spoiler quote newlines!

Comment: For newlines after a spoiler quote, put two spaces at the end of the spoiler line: ">!Spoilertext  " (OK...**I** can't put double-spaces in a comment, so pretend there are 2 there)

Comment: @hagfy Fun fact, even if you used code formatting you _still_ couldn't. `this   has   three`, `this has one`. Comments on StackExchange are weird.

Answer (score 1):

My Guess:

> Ice Cream

Because:

> Each food comes from a different part of the world, while both Apple pie and Hot dogs are commonly associeted with the USA. Since Gramps has already had an American course i think he will go with Ice Cream!

Comment: This wouldn't be nice if it was the answer... I mean as an European I do not associate apple pie with USA.

Comment: I guess apple pie existed before USA

Comment: I'm European (British) and I definitely associate Apple Pie with the USA...

Comment: @DannyJames You don't associate it with Grandma? (Also British)

Comment: @J_mie6 I do associate that with Grandma (French)

Comment: Apples were originally from Germany, after all.

Comment: @Nank We have access to at least one Apple Pie receipe from [1381](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_pie#English_style) - not just before the USA, but before Columbus was even born, let alone crossed the Atlantic...

Comment: funny, despite being American I thought maybe hot dogs were associated with Germany, I was thinking there was a roughly eastward progression of where the foods are from, though it doesn't end up being the case with Pho and Tandoori Chicken